# how to set itunes application requirements for ios applicaiton?

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store-connect

How does itunes sets the application requirements ?

I have a iPhone application that is on AppStore but i can't find it from my iPad 3, just from my iPad 1. I can find it from all my iPhones.
   I want the application to be available for all, iPhone/iPod/iPad but on iPad to run in compatibility mode.

On the iTunes page of the app i have the requirements like so: *"**Requirements**: Compatible with iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4, iPhone 4S, iPhone 5, iPod touch (3rd generation), iPod touch (4th generation), iPod touch (5th generation) and iPad. Requires iOS 4.3 or later. This app is optimized for iPhone 5."*

So how does the Requirements field is completed ? 
My applications has Targeted Device Family -> iPhone and in Target -> Summary -> Device -> iPhone

Comment: when did you last build it with the regular SDK?  Is it possible that it has not been built in a while?

Comment: I built it two weeks ago. I can run it from xCode to my iPad 3.